# ListView selected index is being drawed outside its scope

Tags: flutter

I have two lists, and both have a selected index that is highlighted.

When the selected index is pushed out of the visible scope, it is still being drawed on top of other widgets, generating an unexpected result.

How can I prevent it from drawing a highlighted index outside its boundaries?

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dual ListView with Divider Example'),
        ),
        body: DualListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DualListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DualListViewState createState() => _DualListViewState();
}

class _DualListViewState extends State<DualListView> {
  int selectedIndex1 = 0; // Default selected index for the first list
  int selectedIndex2 = 0; // Default selected index for the second list

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('List 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 100, // Updated number of items in the first list
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                tileColor: selectedIndex1 == index ? Colors.red : null, // Red if selected
                title: Text('Item ${index + 1} of List 1'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex1 = index; // Update selected index on tap
                  });
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 2, // Height of the divider
          color: Colors.blueAccent, // Color of the divider
        ),
        Text('List 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 100, // Updated number of items in the second list
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                tileColor: selectedIndex2 == index ? Colors.green : null, // Red if selected
                title: Text('Item ${index + 1} of List 2'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex2 = index; // Update selected index on tap
                  });
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: @Ivo That's it, you nailed it! Thank you!